# Use Livereload when local server is run from a virtual machine?

Tags: livereload

Im using Virtualbox on my PC to run Ubuntu which is my local development environment. The web browsers that im using the view the site are run from Windows.

How can I set up Livereload? If I install Livereload in Ubuntu then it cant reload my web browsers in Windows. If I install Livereload in Windows then I cant find the files for it to watch as they are not part of the normal file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Potential quick solution: just use my [adhoc web server](https://github.com/Leftium/adhoc).** Two of its features are:

1. Simple to install/use
2. LiveReload built-in

(note: only these file extensions are monitored: `htm, html, css, js, json, png, gif, php, php5, py, rb, erb`. Other file types can be monitored, but that will require modification to adhoc.)

---

**Otherwise, your question needs more info:**

- How are you serving your web pages?
- What have you done to get LiveReload to work?
- Are your getting any error messages?

**Some info to help you start using LiveReload:**

LiveReload needs two components. Make sure you satisfy all the requirements:

1. A LiveReload server. The server sends notifications to clients whenever changes are made to the files on the server (over a web socket). Note this server is not necessarily the web server.
2. A LiveReload client. The client opens a connection to a LiveReload server. When it receives notifications from the server, it reloads or modifies the page as appropriate. Usually the client is simply a web browser that loads a special `livereload.js` JavaScript file. This JavaScript file can be manually added to the HTML file or "injected" by the web server. Adhoc automatically injects the script for you. There are web browser extensions that will also inject the script for you.

Answer (score 0):

To get livereload working with such a setup isn't really much different than getting it working in any other setup. All you need is a service that monitors the files in your dev environment and listens to connections from the browsers viewing the site.

In my dev setup running on linux mint I use [Guard LiveReload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) which runs on top of ruby to provide a livereload server. It doesn't matter if I'm connecting locally or from my desktop at home, as long as `livereload.js` (being served by the livereload server) can be reached, the browser will receive notification and refresh whenever something is changed.

To set it up all you need to do is install and configure [Guard LiveReload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) in your Ubuntu environment (which in turn requires [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) and [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) - instructions are on the [Guard LiveReload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) page). Once the livereload service is running you can connect to it either by using some browser extension or by [adding it to your html](http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86180-how-do-i-add-the-script-tag-manually).